# My WCF Service won't return one particular class

Tags: c#, wcf

I have been successfully sending objects using a WCF service, but there is one class that doesn't work. The WCF service will build, and I can invoke the function that returns the object in the WCF Test Client, but I cannot use the service once I have updated the service reference in the project that's the consumer.

Here is a copy of the class

```
//[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class TillCompanySystem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    // Internal private member variables
    private String _sTillCompanySystemID = "";
    private String _sValue = "";

    // Events
    //[field: NonSerialized]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Constructor
    public TillCompanySystem()
    {

    }

    // Public properties
    #region Public Properties

    // Public properties
    [DataMember]
    public String TillCompanySystemID
    {
        get { return _sTillCompanySystemID; }
        set
        {
            _sTillCompanySystemID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TillCompanySystemID"));
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public String Value
    {
        get { return _sValue; }
        set
        {
            _sValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
        }
    }

    // End region public properties
    #endregion

    // All objects need to support ToString
    public override String ToString()
    {
        return TillCompanySystemID.ToString();
    }

    // Public Events
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }
}
```

I really have no idea why this doesn't work. The only difference I can think of between this and other classes is that previously it was serializable, but I can't see how that would make any difference now. However, if I view the class from the metadata the class still appears to be serializable. I have tried rebuilding everything and that hasn't fixed it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Ed

Comment: In what way can't you use the service?  Do you get an error?

Comment: I've tried a quick test app and the entity is returned as expected. Of course, only the public properties (DataMembers) are serialized. i.e. the server implementations of `ToString()` and `OnPropertyChanged` aren't pulled across to the client proxy class. The `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface is recognized by Visual Studio during proxy generation and is re-implemented in the proxy.

Comment: When I update the service reference, there is no service that is available. I right click on the service reference and view in object browser, the service is not available. I have seen this previously when I have added new functions to the service and have not made the classes datacontracts.

Comment: How do you return this class from your service? I mean is it possible to show the method returning this Class (or perhaps accepting it as parameter)?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it wasn't working was that the someone had made the project reference a compiled version of the datalayer project which meant that this class was always accessible and I have been able to add new classes to the project and it found them, but it wouldn't rebuild this particular class to make it a datacontract since it existed in compiled form.